# how to work with many to many relationships in Microsoft access?

Tags: database, microsoft-access

I'm trying to set up a new access database relating plants to the chemicals they contain. I understand that it's a many to many relationship, because many plants can contain the same chemical, and the same plant can obviously have multiple chemicals. I've tried to set up a junction table, and create the many to many relationship that way, but it's still not clear to me as I'm building the database and entering data how I tell access which chemicals are in which plants? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I need to get going with this project quickly.

Comment: Is your question about creating an appropriate database schema, about creating an appropriate user interface or about importing data from somewhere? We are not going to tell you how to make a whole application here. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database schema for an m-to-n relation where each plant/chemical combination exists only once, looks like this:

```
Table Plant                                                     Table Chemical
+-----------+                                                   +--------------+
|PK PlantID | <----+                                      +---> |PK ChemiclaID |
+-----------+      |     Table PlantChemical              |     +--------------+
|   Name    |      |     +---------------------------+    |     |   Name       |
|           |      +----o|PK FK PlantID              |    |     |              |
|           |            |PK FK ChemicalID           |o---+     |              |
+-----------+            +---------------------------+          +--------------+
                         |      Percentage (optional)|
                         |                           |
                         |                           |
                         +---------------------------+
```

I.e., in the junction table the primary key (PK) consists of `PlantID` and `ChemicalID`, because you want to assign each chemical only once to a given plant. A plant can still have many chemicals and a chemical can still be assigned to many plants.

The junction table `PlantChemical` has a foreign key (FK) to the `Plant` table and to the `Chemical` table. The foreign key to the `Plant` table should cascade deletes, so that you can easily delete a plant. The foreign key to the `Chemical` table should **not** cascade deletes, because you should not be able to delete a chemical that a plant contains.

It is a good idea to have a unique index on the plant and chemical names to speed up searches and to avoid duplicate entries.

in Access `Plant.PlantID` and `Chemical.ChemicalID` should be `AutoNumber` columns.

`PlantChemical.PlantID` and `PlantChemical.ChemicalID` should be `Numeric Long` columns.

---

In the UI, let the user select one plant from the `Plant` table and several chemicals from the `Chemical` table. For each of these chemicals, insert one record into the junction table with the given `PlantID` and `ChemicalID`.

The user will then select another plant and do the same there.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed. Apologies for my initial question being unclear, I've gone through an entire goodwill community foundation course, and looked at database design chapters from elsewhere, but they kept glazing over the nuts and bolts of many to many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Assume table Plant with primary key PlantId, and table Chemical with primary key ChemicalId.

Table PlantChemical would have two columns: PlantId and ChemicalId. There should be an index on each of these columns - NOT a unique index as the purpose is multiple entries for each Plant and each Chemical, and you want to go from Plant to Chemical (as example query below which needs an index on PlantId) and also from Chemical to Plant (so it needs an index on ChemicalId). So you might want to put in an AutoIncrment column to be the Primary key (I would).

You can then relate the two with something like

```
select *
from Plant p
inner join PlantChemical pc on pc.PlantId = p.PlantId
inner join Chemical c om c.ChemicalId = pc.ChemicalId
```

(This may be incorrect syntax for Access. I remember Access has opinions on the order of the coluln names in the on parts of the joins, but don't have …. Access right now.0